# why the javascript taking the file path as fake path in JSP?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

Hi I have a JSP file where there is two input box one file type another is file type which hidden and alsotwo button one is for browse and load button.If i click the button in jS i have called the File input box to browse the file but when try to populate the file path in the nput Box its taking that as Fake Path.

Below is my code .Can any body tell how to fix this issue in JSp?

```js
 <script type='text/javascript'>
                function fileupload() {
                    $('#excelfile').click();
                }

                function Populateinput() {
                    var filePath = $('#excelfile').val();
                    //alert(filePath);
                    document.getElementById("filename").value = filepath;
                }
            </script>
```

```html
<div>
                            <label style="color: black;">Excel Input:</label>
                            <input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="filename" name="filename">
                            <button type="button" value="Browse" onclick="fileupload();" style="color: black;">Browse</button>
                            <input type="submit" value="Load" style="color: black;" value="Load">
                            <input type="file" id="excelfile" name="excelfile" style="display: none;" onchange="Populateinput();">
                        </div>
```

Comment: You cannot trick the user into selecting a file without his consent. Security issue, even if your use case would be legit.

Answer (score 0):

A full filename including path selected via an `<input type="file">` tag is NOT available to Javascript.  The contents of the file can be uploaded to a server, but the file path itself is kept secret from the client for security reasons.

See [this MDN description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/name) for details and per [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications), you can access only the filename (without path), the size and the type of the file.

Comment: so is there any alternative way to achieve this jSP page .PLease reply

Comment: @SnehasishDas - You can't get the actual file path - that is a security design.  Beyond that, you haven't described what problem you're really trying to solve so I don't know what else to suggest.

Comment: the name of the file is available as eg. `input.files[0].name`; the path is not available, as you mentioned. ed: you say both it is and isn't...

Comment: @jfriend00 in that case how can i read the upload file in servlet by line by line

Comment: @dandavis do have any idea how to achieve that i mean in my case there is a excel sheet in any drive that i have to read programatically in Servlet according to Tab wise .I am able to read the file if i pass the Path of the upload file from UI part (JSP) .

Comment: @SnehasishDas You can read the excel sheet if it's on the server. If you want to read it from the client machine, the client must first send the file to you. Sure, you can do it directly on their machine with a Java applet, given that your application is requesting the appropriate permissions and the user accepted them. But in javascript / jsp, you just can't. It's not even worth trying.